# Using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to send data to DataBase

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

```
package com.techm.template;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

public class InsertRecordInDatabaseWithJdbcTemplate {

    private static final String driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

    private static final String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";

    private static final String dbUsername = "SYSTEM";

    private static final String dbPassword = "9848451415";

    private static final String sql = "INSERT INTO employee(firstname,lastname,username,password) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";


    private static DataSource dataSource;



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        dataSource = getDataSource();

        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.setFirstname("Surya Teja");
        e.setLastname("Tammana");
        e.setUsername("surya_kvm");
        e.setPassword("9848451415");

        int result = saveRecord(e);
        if(result != 0){
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Failure");
        }

    }



   public static int saveRecord(Employee e) {

       NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);

       SqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();

       Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("firstnames", e.getFirstname());
        parameters.put("lastname", e.getLastname());
        parameters.put("username", e.getUsername());
        parameters.put("password", e.getPassword());

        int result = template.update(sql, parameters);
        return result;
   }



 public static DriverManagerDataSource getDataSource() {

 DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
 dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
 dataSource.setUrl(url);
 dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
 dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
 return dataSource;

    }
}
```

Employee.java

```
package com.techm.template;

public class Employee {

private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String username;
private String password;
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}
public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}




}
```

Console

Jan 22, 2017 12:25:24 AM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: SQL [INSERT INTO employee(firstname,lastname,username,password) VALUES(?,?,?,?)]: given 4 parameters but expected 0
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:221)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.newPreparedStatementCreator(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.getPreparedStatementCreator(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:351)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:292)
    at com.techm.template.InsertRecordInDatabaseWithJdbcTemplate.saveRecord(InsertRecordInDatabaseWithJdbcTemplate.java:64)
    at com.techm.template.InsertRecordInDatabaseWithJdbcTemplate.main(InsertRecordInDatabaseWithJdbcTemplate.java:40)

Answer (score 7):

You are using positional parameters in your SQL query. This doesn't work because you are using the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` which requires named parameters. Just modify your query to use named parameters like that:

```
"INSERT INTO employee(firstname, lastname, username, password) VALUES(:firstname, :lastname, :username, :password)"
```

Also you could use the Employee object as a parameter source:

```
public static int saveRecord(Employee e) {
        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        SqlParameterSource params = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(e);

        int result = template.update(sql, params);
        return result;
   }
```

The `BeanPropertySqlParameterSource`will use Employees properties to set the parameters.